# process of uploading an image through the frontend, saving it to an S3 bucket using AWS Lambda, and also saving relevant information in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, upload, amazon-dynamodb

I don't know  the right path how to upload image through front end using aws lambda in s3 bucket and same information also saved in  dynamodb

don't know the actual process of uploading an image through the frontend, saving it to an S3 bucket using AWS Lambda, and also saving relevant information in DynamoDB

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. You are saying you want to "upload image through font end using aws lambda in s3 bucket" -- Lambda is not front-end technology

Answer (score 0):

This is the flow I would suggest:

1. Put your image to S3 using [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html)
2. Enable a Lambda trigger for PutObject Events in your bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html
3. Inside that Lambda function obtain the required information and use [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) to write that item to DynamoDB.

[This video](https://youtu.be/UVfs3_gYOzg?si=he3QEgQi3egN9N0_) may help but could be overkill depending on your experience with GraphQL.